# Web 8.5 how to configure Target Language for Pages and DCPs?

Tags: web8.5, configuration, deployer

Content Delivery transforms code in DWT (Dreamweaver Template) into several programming languages (Java, dotNet, TCDL).

A programming language that is transformed to is configured in `tcdl_conf.xml` of `Content Deployer`.

There are following 2 properties in `tcdl_conf.xml`.

```
<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="VIRTUALMACHINELANG"/>
<Property Name="tcdl.page.target.language" Value="VIRTUALMACHINELANG" />
```

The documentation describes that by configuring those propeties, Pages and Dynamic Component Presentations can be transformed into defferent programming languages.

[Enabling publishing of Pages with REL format Dynamic Component Presentations](http://a-8f56-f38787acb1fe&filename=GUID-3ED3EF09-4EE6-48B2-A618-D16634BB9DB8.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-3ED3EF09-4EE6-48B2-A618-D16634BB9DB8&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dtcdl.page.target.language&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1505808106317&currentQuery=tcdl.page.target.language&currentScope=)

My goal is following.

- Pages are transformed into JSP
- DCPs are transformed into TCDL

I have tried following configurations, but I couldn't get desired result.

**Trial 1**

Configurations:

`tcdl.target.language=rel` and `tcdl.page.target.language=jsp`

Results:

`Pages` are `TCDL` and `DCPs` are `TCDL`

**Trial 2**

Configurations:

`tcdl.target.language` is not configured and `tcdl.page.target.language` is `JSP`

Results:

`Pages` are `dotNet` and `DCPs` are `TCDL`

**Trial 3**

Configurations:

`tcdl.target.language=jsp` and `tcdl.page.target.language` is not configured

Results:

`Pages` are `JSP` and `DCPs` are `JSP`

How can I achieve my goal (Pages are JSP and DCPs are TCDL)?

Answer (score 3):

Hotfix for this issue is available. With it installed you should be able to get a Page in JSP and Component Presentation in REL format with following settings in `tcdl_conf.xml`:

```
<Property Name="tcdl.target.language" Value="rel"/>
<Property Name="tcdl.page.target.language" Value="jsp" />
```

Please contact SDL Customer Support to obtain a hotfix package.

Answer (score 2):

We've been struggling with a similar problem. As far as we can tell, now that the setting has moved to the deployer, you only have one place where you can configure it.

This was a logical consequence of moving some things from the Publication Target to the deployer. What came as a surprise was that the Component Template was no longer leading. The deployer wins, no matter what you do.

The best solution we've come up with so far is to run up an extra deployer (which implies also a new CD environment).